# How do I interpret this Pascal part to C++?

Tags: c++, pascal

How do I write this  record and procedure in C++? How do I translate the code to class and methods instead of direct translation?

```
type
complex=record
im,re:real;
end;

procedure NumberMultiplication(a:complex; var b:complex; k:byte);
  begin
    b.re:=a.re*k;
    b.im:=a.im*k;
  end;
```

Comment: How about learning C++?

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard library already provides this functionality.

Include the header `<complex>`, use the type `std::complex<double>`, express multiplication with ordinary `*`.

Example:

```
#include <complex>

using Complex   = std::complex<double>;
using Byte      = unsigned char;

auto operator*( Byte const b, Complex const& c )
    -> Complex
{ return Complex( b )*c; }

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    Byte const      b = 42;
    Complex const   c = {2, 3};         // 2 + 3*i

    cout << b*c << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you could:

```
struct complex {
    double im, re;
};
```

The procedure could then be written as:

```
void NumberMultiplication(complex a, complex &b, byte k)
{
    b.re = a.re * k;
    b.im = a.im * k;
}
```

This is a direct translation from the Pascal implementation; there are perhaps better ways to write this in C++ depending on your overall goals.

Comment: +1 But in C++ you could put the method within the structure, isn't it?

Comment: @alvits: You could, yes. But that wouldn't be a translation of the Pascal code.

Comment: I don't see the difference between using class or structure

Comment: @user3582421 - Maybe you should rephrase your question if you want the code to be translated to class and methods instead of direct translation.

Comment: Of course, in C++ you could just use `std::complex<double>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own structure

```
struct complex
{
 double re, im;
}

void NumberMultiplication(const complex a; complex &b, short int k)
{
  b.re = a.re * k;
  b.im = a.im * k;
}
```

(why the byte -- short int type???).

I prefer a better approach, which is to

```
#include <complex>

std::complex<double> a, b; 
short int k;  
b = a * k;
```

(still perplexed by the short int). You can check the complex class reference at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned, the most direct translation is to replace the Pascal `record` with a `struct`. Note that the C++ equivalent of `byte` is `unsigned char`, therefore the most direct translation would be:

```
struct complex
{
  double re, im;
};

void NumberMultiplication(complex a, complex& b, unsigned char k)
{
   b.re = a.re*k;
   b.im = a.im * k;
}
```

However, this is not the best translation. The first thing to mention is that C++, unlike Pascal, allows to return structured types (I think there are Pascal dialects which allow that, too). Therefore you can change `NumberMultiplication` to a function returning `complex`:

```
complex NumberMultiplication(complex a, unsigned char k)
{
  complex b { a.re*k, a.im * k };
  return b;
}
```

Note that in the above code, I've used the possibility to initialize a C++ `struct` directly at local variable definition. However you can do even better by giving `complex` a constructor:

```
struct complex
{
  double re, im;
  complex(double real, double imag = 0); // constructor declaration
};

// inline is a hint for the compiler to optimize by inserting that code
// into calling code
inline complex::complex(double real, double imag):
  re(real),
  im(imag)   // these initialize the members
{
  // here you could write other code to be executed on initialization
  // (not needed in this case)
}

complex NumberMultiplication(complex a, unsigned char k)
{
  return complex(a.re * k, a.im * k);
}
```

Note that the second argument of the constructor (`double imag`) has a default argument (`= 0`); this enables to omit the imaginary part; moreover, since now the constructor can be called with just one argument (and is not marked as `explicit`), this also enables implicit conversion to double, that is, you now could write e.g.

```
complex z = NumberMultiplication(3.0, 7);
```

and this would mean the same as

```
complex z = NumberMultiplication(complex(3.0, 0.0), 7);
```

The next improvement is to use C++'s operator overloading: There's no need to invent a fancy function name for an operation which we would normally use the multiplication operator `*` for; we can define that multiplication operator for our own types by simply using the special function name `operator*`:

```
complex operator*(complex a, unsigned char k)
{
  return complex(a.re * k, a.im * k);
}
```

with that you can now simply write e. g.

```
complex x(1,2), y;
unsigned char c = 42;
y = x*c;
```

Of course you might also sometimes want to write `y=c*x` instead and want that to work, too. Fortunately you can do that thanks to function overloading: Just add

```
complex operator*(unsigned char k, complex a)
{
  return complex(a.re * k, a.im * k);
}
```

and the compiler will select the correct function to call from the types.

Next, we can improve the `complex` struct to make it a proper class by hiding the member variables. We provide accessor functions to read the real and imaginary parts. So we now get:

```
class complex
{
public:
  complex(double real, double imag=0);
  double real();
  double imag();
};

inline complex::complex(doube real, double imag):
  re(real),
  im(imag)
{
};

inline double complex::real()
{
  return re;
}

inline double complex::imag()
{
  return im;
}

complex operator*(complex a, unsigned char k)
{
  return complex(a.real() * k, a.imag() * k);
}

complex operator*(unsigned char k, complex a)
{
  return complex(a.real() * k, a.imag() * k);
}
```

Now complex numbers need of course a lot more operations than just multiplication; but fortunately you can save yourself all that work because someone already did it for you. In C++ exists a header `complex` which contains a complete implementation of complex numbers. Therefore you can just write

```
#include <complex>
```

and use the type `std::complex<double>` everywhere where your Pascal code uses the self-defined `complex` type.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret it the following way

```
strcut complex
{
   double im;
   double re;
};


complex operator *( const complex &c, int k )
{
   return { k * c.im, k * c.re };
}   

complex operator *( int k, const complex &c )
{
   return { k * c.im, k * c.re };
}
```

That is the operation will be commutative. You can write

```
complex c = { 1, 2 };

c = 3 * c;

c = c * 3;
```

Or if your compiler does not support initializer list then

```
strcut complex
{
   double im;
   double re;
};


complex operator *( const complex &c, int k )
{
   complex tmp = { k * c.im, k * c.re };

   return tmp;     
}   

complex operator *( int k, const complex &c )
{
   complex tmp = { k * c.im, k * c.re };

   return tmp;     
}
```